# Relative path - dealing with files many directories away

Tags: javascript, path

It's been quite some time since I've done front-end development and I'm having some issues... My current file is at this location on my server:

```
/home/www/mysite/sites/all/custom_includes/roster/user_roster.php
```

I have a js file located at:

```
/home/www/lib/jquery/jquery.fancybox.js
```

If it was a php file I was trying to include, I could do something like this:

```
$jsPath = '/home/www/lib/jquery';
require_once($jsPath.'/jquery.fancybox.js');
```

But it doesn't seem to work with a script tag. I tried it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $jsPath; ?>/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

but it evaluates to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/www/lib/jquery/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

which gives me a page not found error. Am I stuck using 10,000 levels of ../ in my script src path to get the file? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about it from the client's point of view when dealing with js.

Your path should be:
/lib/jquery/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js

The client's paths are relative to your web server root, in this case being /home/www
Also remember that you cannot access files at a higher level than /home/www from the client without going through a server-side script.

Comment: I've tried that as well. It still gives me a file not found error.

Comment: Try viewing the file directly from your browser and see if it's correct.

Comment: It still gives me a file not found error. But when I stick a php file in that directory and use require_once, it finds it with no problem, so I know the path is correct.

Comment: PHP paths and web server paths are completely different. For example: http://www.domain.com/example.js does not point to /example.js it will point to /home/www/example.js (Assuming /home/www/ is your web server root)